# How can I fetch an image in an intuitive way using Angular HttpClient?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a backend that returns an image. I can call this backend fine in the browser. The image gets displayed, all OK.

The response type is image/jpeg.

Now, I'm investigating options for how I can fetch the image using Angular HttpClient.

If I try to just issue a GET call, I can see the image downloaded fine in the Network tab of the browser.

Angular, however, gives me an error:
[image]

Code:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThumbnailService {
  private thumbnailUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/thumbnail';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public findOne(classifiedId: number): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'image/jpeg',
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.thumbnailUrl}/${classifiedId}`, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

From what I understand...

- Angular tries to parse the response as JSON because of the  type
- There are lots of overloaded methods available for how to parse the response, depending on how I type the response
- If I use Blob as return type:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThumbnailService {
  private thumbnailUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/thumbnail';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public findOne(classifiedId: number): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'image/jpeg',
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<Observable<Blob>>(`${this.thumbnailUrl}/${classifiedId}`, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

I get the same error.

Looking at the Blob type, it seems to have some structural expectations that I don't currently fulfill...

Is there a simple(r) way to fetch an image using Angular HttpClient? Am I missing something?

Setting the headers along with setting responseType results in compilation error, both with response typed as any and as Blob:

> Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; responseType: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
>     Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Comment: You should set responseType as 'blob' to fetch the image as Blob. Refer - https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType

Answer (score 4):

You are only type casting to `Blob`, not actually parsing it as a Blob. If you want angular to parse it as a `Blob`, you have to set the `responseType` accordingly.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThumbnailService {
  private thumbnailUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/thumbnail';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public findOne(classifiedId: number): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'image/jpeg',
      }),
      responseType: 'blob' // This tells angular to parse it as a blob, default is json
    };
    return this.http.get<Observable<Blob>>(`${this.thumbnailUrl}/${classifiedId}`, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-download-image-example-e9ybwc)

Answer (score 0):

For receiving the BLOB in the response you have to pass a responseType parameter into the HTTP get method. Here are the available overloads of Angular HttpClient get method [Http Get-Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) check the overload#5.